# Converting conditional Perl Regex matching to VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, perl

In Perl, you can use regex matching in conditional statements, *e.g.*

```perl
if ($myvar =~ /(pattern1)(pattern2)/) {
    $var1 = $1;
    $var2 = $2;
} elseif ($myvar =~ /(pattern3)(pattern4)/) {
   ...
} elseif ($myvar =~ /(pattern5)(pattern6)/) {
   ...
}
```

In VB.NET, I've typically converted this as something like:

```vbnet
Dim re1 As New Regex("(pattern1)(pattern2)")
Dim re2 As New Regex("(pattern3)(pattern4)")
Dim re3 As New Regex("(pattern3)(pattern4)")
Dim m as match

if re1.IsMatch(myvar) Then
    m = re1.Match(myvar)
    var1 = m.Groups(1).Value
    var2 = m.Groups(2).Value
Else If re2.IsMatch(myvar) Then
    m = re2.Match(myvar)
    ...
Else If re3.IsMatch(myvar) Then
    m = re3.Match(myvar)
    ...
End
```

Is it possible to simplify the .NET equivalent so that it is not looking for the match success, and then performing the match again, more akin to the inline Perl? I know I could create multiple matching variables and perform the match ahead of time, but that still feels wasteful since it is performs all the matches ahead of time rather than only when needed.

Comment: Could maybe rework the logic.  Preform the match to get m, then do the conditional on the value of m

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`Match.Success` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Group_Success%5D) after running `Regex.Match`. If it is `true`, you can access group values:

```vb
Dim re1 As New Regex("(pattern1)(pattern2)")
Dim re2 As New Regex("(pattern3)(pattern4)")
Dim m as Match

m = re1.Match(myvar)
If (m.Success = True) Then
    var1 = m.Groups(1).Value
    var2 = m.Groups(2).Value
Else
    m = re2.Match(myvar)
    If (m.Success = True) Then
        var1 = m.Groups(1).Value
        var2 = m.Groups(2).Value
    End
End
```

Comment: That works for a simple `IF...ELSE...` condition. The Perl I'm trying to convert has multiple `elseif` conditions. I updated my original question to reflect this. I'm actually considering creating an extension method on a Regex object, performing the match there, returning the match ByRef, and success and a function result.

Comment: @Matt You may do whatever you want from here. This is how you use a single match operation and then get the values if there is a match. Perl is not VB.NET and there are no any "global variables" after you perform a regex match.